# script scope in elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, I would like to know what variables are available in the scope of a script used in a (sub)aggregation.

I already read resources on [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) and [text scoring in scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html) as well as the documentation of most aggregation types but could not find a comprehensive reference of what can be used depending on the situation.

From what I could gather, most scripts in aggregations are run **per-hit** and have access to the following scope:

- document fields, through `doc['field_name'].*`
- document as parsed from index, through `_source`
- stored fields, through `_fields['field_name']`
- document score, through `_score`
- shard statistics, through `_index.*`
- per-shard field statistics, through `_index['field_name'].*`
- per-shard term statistics, through `_index['field_name']['term'].*`

The *Scripted Metric* aggregation also exposes an `_agg` variable in **per-shard** & **per-hit** scripts (init, map & combine scripts) and an `_aggs` variable at the **coordinating node level** (reduce script).
Of course, the map script can also access every other per-hit variable as defined above.
I could not find documentation indicating whether `_index*` was available in per-shard scripts but it would seem logic.
Also, scripted_metric is the only case of scripts at the shard or coordinating node level that I could find.

The *Signicant Terms* aggregation has a special case of running a scoring script **per-bucket**, with the following variables in scope:

- `_subset_freq`,
- `_superset_freq`,
- `_subset_size`,
- `_superset_size`

However it does not seem to have access to other bucket-dependent stuff, like bucket key (term) or single-value metric sub-aggregations, which is a pitty because it would be super-useful (at least, I could not find any documentation on how to access such bucket-dependent information).

The *Terms* aggregation also has a special case of a value script (when both parameters `field` and `script` are defined), which can only access a `_value` variable.

Is the information summed up here accurate/complete?